# jQuery slideDown function vertical jump at end of animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have researched this problem extensively and have not been able to find an answer to this.

Here is a JSFiddle showing the issue I am having:

http://jsfiddle.net/8cfLa8tk/

You will notice that every time you click the button to add the link, it will add it but then jump at the end of the animation.

I want to have the link appended, be hidden, then have the slideDown animation reveal the link without it jumping and I am pulling my hair out here trying to figure out the issue.

and because it's forcing me to write code here even though it won't make sense without the HTML and CSS:

```
links++;
    $('#some_links').append('<li id="link_' + links + '"></li>');
    $('<div style="display:none;"><a href="#">Link ' + links + '</a></div>')
        .appendTo($('#link_' + links))
        .slideDown('fast');
```

Comment: So add the `html` and `css` here too.

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align: bottom;` to `#some_links li` **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p0wpfLbd/)**

Comment: You are a lifesaver. How do you even troubleshoot something like this as fast as you did?

Comment: Practice makes a man perfect (not calling myself perfect though :P)